# Display image from storage in view

Tags: php, laravel, image, file-upload

I have a form with multiple fields which stores information including an image upload. **There is also an edit view:**

```
Route::PUT('/link/{link}', function (Request $request, Link $link) {
  $request->validate([
    'name' => 'required|max:255',
    'title' => 'required|max:255',
    'cell' => 'required|max:255',
    'tel' => 'required|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|max:255',
    'website' => 'required|url|max:255',
    'location' => 'required|max:255',
    'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
  ]);

  $img = $request->file('image');

  $newfilename = $request->name;

  $img->move(public_path("/uploads"), $newfilename);

  $link->update($request->all());

  return redirect('/');
});
```

The initial submit and edit works fine along with changing the image file name and storing it in the uploads folder.

**The path generated being:**

```
public/uploads/exampleFileName.jpg
```

The problem here is when it comes to displaying the image in the home view. The code below generates a 404 not found with an additional /tmp/ path which I have no idea about where it comes from.

**Code in home view:**

```
@foreach ($links as $link)
    <div class="link-box">
      <h5 class="off-white-txt">Card [# {{ $link->id }}]</h5>
      <h5 class="off-white-txt"><span class="pool-blue-txt">Name: </span>{{ $link->name }}</h5>
      <h5 class="off-white-txt"><span class="pool-blue-txt">Title: </span>{{ $link->title }}</h5>
      <h5 class="off-white-txt"><span class="pool-blue-txt">Cell: </span>{{ $link->cell }}</h5>
      <h5 class="off-white-txt"><span class="pool-blue-txt">Tel: </span>{{ $link->tel }}</h5>
      <h5 class="off-white-txt"><span class="pool-blue-txt">Email: </span>{{ $link->email }}</h5>
      <h5 class="off-white-txt"><span class="pool-blue-txt">Website: </span>{{ $link->website }}</h5>
      <h5 class="off-white-txt"><span class="pool-blue-txt">Location: </span>{{ $link->location }}</h5>

  <img src="{{url('uploads'.$link->image) }}" class="off-white-txt">
</div>
```

***The error message in the console:***

```
GET http://192.168.10.10/uploads/tmp/phpdtnTcw 404 (Not Found)
```

**My question is the following; How could I edit my code to point to the correct path and display the image?**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to saving the image instead of moving it? The image isn't store in your application at the time of you moving it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using storage folder to save images then you should use **Storage::url**

make sure to run command **php artisan storage:link**

```
  <img src="{{ Storage::url($link->image) }}" class="off-white-txt">
```

Comment: I agree with this approach. It's better to store the file in storage and create a symbolic link for that directory using the storage:link command then you can just access the storage file as public files. Once you create the link then you can even use assets(path of your file) helper instead of the image tag. You cannot access the files of the storage directory.

Answer (score 0):

The temporary path you are getting is from the image itself.

Why? Because you are not setting the image new path after moving the image, so the image is stored inside a temp storage.

To simplify it, you have indeed saved the image under `public` folder, but the `image` path is still in the `temp` storage. This is where the image resides. This temp storage is the default path for every `UploadedFile` object

You need to explicitly set it's path on the `Link` object, like so:

```
$link->image = 'my new path';
$link->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you cannot access the uploads folder from the view.
I would suggest to create a controller that will get your image in the uploads folder and send a image Response. Something like this :

```
public function showImage($image)
{
    if (!Storage::exists($image->name)) {
        return false;
    }

    $file = Storage::get($image->name);
    $type = Storage::mimeType($image->name);
    $response = Response::make($file, 200)->header("Content-Type", $type);

    return $response;
}
```

Then you just have to call the right route that points to your controller method :

```
<img src="{{ route('getMyImage', $image) }}" />
```

This way you can protect easily the files in your uploads folder (for exemple : put middleware or user control functions ...). Otherwise you can do the `php artisan storage:link` command

Answer (score 0):

These are all valid points although the setup of my framework didn't play well with the suggestions. I have implemented a workaround for now.

**This is the updated code in the web controller:**

```
Route::post('/submit', function (Request $request) {
  $data = $request->validate([
      'name' => 'required|max:255',
      'title' => 'required|max:255',
      'cell' => 'required|max:255',
      'tel' => 'required|max:255',
      'email' => 'required|max:255',
      'website' => 'required|url|max:255',
      'location' => 'required|max:255',
      'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
  ]);

  $img = $request->file('image');
  // Storage::disk('public')->put('uploads', $img);

  $newfilename = $request->name;
  $img->move(public_path("/uploads"), $newfilename);

  $link = tap(new App\Link($data))->save();

  return redirect('/');
});
```

**This is the updated view code:**

```
<img src="/uploads/{{ $link->name }}" class="user-img">
```

***Thank you very much for all the help!***